# I tried to change the username and the password of the Authentication,but i still get a random generated password,which i have to enter to login

Tags: java, spring, authentication

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("blah")
        .password("blah")
        .roles("USER");
    }
```

Comment: @Bean
public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
 return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
 
}
}
and that

Comment: Post some more details

Comment: I am trying to add Spring security to a spring boot project .I add the spring boot-starter security dependency and by default i get a generated pass to enter the logic form, so i can access the site.I am extending webconfigadapter,which lets me acces some core security objects,and using those objects I can tell spring security what to do.I overwrite the config method so i tell spring security those are the username and password but i still get the default password generation in the code

Comment: Its working fine for me, so can you also share the pom.xml file of yours and this whole spring config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring boot is not able to scan your security package for that you need to put your security package or class under the main package where main class of the project reside in the base pack.

If it does not work. Please share project structure and security class code because it will be more helpful to figure out your problem.

Comment: Okey it does work but why it doesnt get my code if i put it in a"security"package in the same project with the same name

Comment: Because **by default** spring boot is able to scan the package those reside under the main package where the main class resides. And to scan the package outside the main package you need to use @ComponentScan(basePackages ="nameofpackage" ) "ComponentScan" annotation above the main class to scan the particular package.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only one admin user, Could you try to set a properties file ?

spring.security.user.name= your name

spring.security.user.password= your password